# SingleOrDefault inside Include will raise the following error :- The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application, and I am using Entity Framework 5. I have the following model method:

```
public SDJoin AllFindSDDetails_J(int id)
{
    var IT360Resource = entities.Resources
                .Include(a => a.ComponentDefinition)
                .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization)
                .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinitions1.SingleOrDefault().SDOrganization)
                .Include(a => a.ResourceState) 
                .SingleOrDefault(a2 => a2.RESOURCEID == tmsSD.Technology.IT360ID);
```

but when this method is being called I get the following exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path    Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The Include path
>   expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.
>   Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select
>   operator for collection navigation properties.

I fixed it by replacing this :

```
  .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinitions1.SingleOrDefault().SDOrganization)
```

with :

```
  .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinitions1.Select(aa=>aa.SDOrganization))
```

So I replaced `SingleOrDefault()` by `Select(aa=>aa...)`

My question is: why can I not define `SingleOrDefault()` inside `.Include()`

Second question: why do I not get any compilation error? I  mean I successfully built my project, but at run-time I got the exception when the method was called.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't get a compilation error because it's valid syntax. Entity framework is a library, and can't detect that kind of error until runtime. As to *why* you can't just load the first foreign row: That's a limitation of EntityFramework. You could avoid it by explicitly loading the foreign row after your first query (and removing it from the `Include`), however.

Comment: @Rob but is using .Select as i am doing  a correct approach to follow? , i mean will this cause the aa.SDOrganization to be eager loaded ?

Comment: Yes, it will cause them to be eagerly loaded (however, it will load *all* of the foreign rows, not just the first)

Answer (score -1):

Did you set any mapping? I don't see any mapping here. You may need to specifically set you object relationships using mapping via either fluent or attribute based mapping [entity mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

Comment: which mapping u r talking about ?

Comment: Take a look at link. EF will infer the relationships based on your model but it doesn't always know what you intend to do. Your actual relationships may be different from the average so ef may not be able to infer it from the model. In such cases its best to create a mapping and include it in the model builder. It will define the correct navigation properties.